# Odd Even Linked List Run Time Error for one particular input. Runs fine for everything else

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, puzzle

I am trying to solve a problem from LeetCode.

**Problem**

Given a singly linked list, group all odd nodes together followed by the even nodes. Please note here we are talking about the node number and not the value in the nodes.

You should try to do it in place. The program should run in O(1) space complexity and O(nodes) time complexity.

Example:
Given 1->2->3->4->5->NULL,
return 1->3->5->2->4->NULL.

**My Solution:**

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* oddEvenList(ListNode* head) {

        ListNode *even, *firsteven, *odd, *curr;

        if(head == NULL)
            return NULL;

        odd = head;
        even = head;
        curr = head;

        if(head->next) {
            even = even->next;
            firsteven = head->next;
        }
        else return head;

        if(head->next->next)
            curr = head->next->next;
        else return head;

        while(curr) {
            even->next = curr->next;
            curr->next = NULL;
            odd->next = curr;
            curr->next = firsteven;
            odd = odd->next;
            even = even->next;
            even->next ? curr = even->next : curr = NULL;
        }

        return head;
    }
};
```

My solution works perfectly well for all inputs except for inputs of size 3. 
For an input 1->2->3 I am getting a run time error. I have done a dry run several times. I am not sure why I am getting a run time error.

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

```
even->next = curr->next;
```

When current is set to the last element (3), you're trying curr->next, which will result in an error.

Comment: But why should that cause an error? curr->next is set to NULL. So shouldn't even->next simply be assigned equal to NULL? How does that cause a run time error?